Single phase load flow usecasee
I am learning power systems and now reading about load flow. I understand loadflow is used to initialise a network to steady state. I started by building a single phase network in Simulink which has an ac source, and couple of cascaded rl load blocks with rl transmission lines. Simulink threw an error when I connect the load flow bus blocks to this model and when I compute load flow from powergui. However an equivalent three phase network  was working fine with load flow. Now I have a question if matlab can compute loadflow of single phase system and in what circumstances is a single phase load flow made.
Edit:
Adding the Simulink single phase loadflow model



Care to share that error message, maybe? It's rather hard to help you decipher the error if you don't tell us what error you get. And maybe you could show some screenshots of the block diagram?

@MrGerber Added the model screenshot and error message.

Are you sure the 'load flow bus' can be connected to a circuit? You may need a converter to get from one to the other.

@voltage spike Can you explain what sort of converter is required?

Please show the equivalent three-phase network, & simulation results.
